# Can anyone help with Pi 4 mplayer HDMI audio passthrough?

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have a Pi4, and am using pipresents to create museum touchscreen exhibits. Pipresents plays audio using mplayer. I would like to play a 5.1 surround sound ac3 file, which gives some spatial orientation using 6 speakers in the room.

I have an audio extractor which accepts the HDMI from the pi, and is supposed to grab the multichannel ac3, send it to various speakers powered by a Rockville surround sound system, and pass the video to my touchscreen.

Everything works except the audio passthrough. I can't get the pi to send the ac3 file, without trying to decode it, out the HDMI0 to my extractor.

But, I'm having no luck enabling alsa, pulse, or mplayer to perform the HDMI passthrough. I've tried a number of forum suggestions, and the mplayer passthrough enable option -ac hwac3, no luck. I get "sample format big-endian AC3 not yet supported"

My understanding is that the pi HDMI sends out only two audio channels. But, I'm assuming it will send the complete ac3 file out those channels, to be decoded and played by the surround sound system.
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: are you certain that the ac3 file gets sent through the HDMI port as a file, not as sound data?

Comment: I am not positive, but I think it does. I was able to play an ac3 file through Kodi over the hardware. Is there an easy way to verify that a file is sent?

Comment: I've been digging in to this issue today, and it seems the problem might be related to the encoding/codec of the ac3 file I'm trying to play. Still learning, but I need to encode the file as s16le. I've been using audacity export ability with ffmpeg, but it says that the s16le codec is not compatible with ac3 file format. Not sure where to go next.